# How to intercept web traffic of a remote computer connected to WAN

Tags: networking, proxy, port-forwarding, lan, wan

I'm able to configure burp proxy to intercept web traffic on my local Network but I don't know how to do the same with a pc not connected to my local Network but to internet (WAN).

How can I configure a remote pc to proxy all the web traffic to burpsuite on my machine?

Comment: You have to set the remote pc's proxy settings to point to your proxy address.

Comment: That's what I want to know. How will the remote pc see my proxy when the pc are not connected to the same Network. What should be my proxy address so that any pc on the WWW can see my proxy address.

Comment: You have to manually set the proxy address in the remote PC.  you need to make your proxy accessible with a public address.

Comment: That's my actual question sir. How to make my proxy accessible with a public address?

Comment: You need to configure port forwarding on your router for your proxy address.  There are many questions and answers on this site that describe how to do that.